# Cookie value not updating on homepage Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, cookie

In Magento2.3, I have cookie value not updating on homepage while its updating on other pages.
Even on incognito browser close and reopen cookie value still exist.

Please suggest me way to make cookie working on homepage as well.
I have followed following tutorial to set/get cookie. [link](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/set-and-get-cookie-in-magento-2/)

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your code how are you updating the cookie value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the page twice in order for the $_COOKIE function to work , at least in my experience